# Indent JSON on save in Vim

Tags: json, vim, indentation, auto-indent

I'm using `elzr/vim-json` for JSON, which works very nicely. `gg=G` indents JSON, and doesn't destroy my buffer if it contains invalid JSON.

Is there a way that I can run `gg=G` on save, but only for JSON files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you are looking for [`autocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html):

```
:autocmd BufWritePre *.json :normal gg=G
```

You can add this line to your vimrc and `gg=G` will be applied to every file matching the `*.json` pattern on save.

Alternatively, you can use `python -m json.tool` to indent your JSON file:

```
:autocmd BufWritePre *.json execute '%!python -m json.tool' | w
```

This command will lint you code using an external command (`python -m json.tool`) and save it to the current buffer (`w`).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The `gg=G` option works much better for me. `json.tool` has an annoying feature in that it returns nothing if the buffer isn't syntactically correct.